# Bretschneider-Brahmagupta-Heron Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, proof-writing, quadrilateral

> **Derive Bretschneider's formula, Brahmagupta's formula and Heron's formula in one memorable elegant proof.**

I ask this question merely to see the creativity of the MSE community when it comes to proof writing. Other than that, simplicity and good presentation is what I'm in search for.

Have fun :D

Comment: Hmm..Nick took my lesson seriously. I think it is best to derive Bretschneider's formula by the not so simple but nice proof, and then list the others as simple corollaries.

Comment: When you say "Bretschneider's formula", do you mean the one he published (1842) or the (of course!) different one that bears his name?

Comment: @Eric: The one which is the expression for the area of a general convex quadrilateral. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider's_formula

Comment: @Nick:  That would be both of them.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BretschneidersFormula.html

Comment: @EricTowers: I was thinking of the 1842 one when I posed this question but since both serve the same purpose, I don't have any inclinations. So, derive whichever one you like. Infact, derive both if you want to. Just don't forget about Brahmagupta and Heron in the process.

Comment: @Nick Brahmagupta and Heron are corollaries of Bretschneider's!

Comment: Either way, I think Bretschneider's Formula is too complex in itself to have a simple proof. I think the Wiki proof is elegant and simple albeit a bit long.

Comment: @Sawarnik: Firstly, yes. They are corollaries. By definition, they are special cases. But just saying they are is too demeaning. And from this question I had hoped someone would at least have created a proof that I could remember like the back of my hand rather than to look up through notes on what the law of cosines were to just get started.

Comment: @Nick, Bretschneider's Formula can be derived from the generalized half-angle formulas.  Once these formulas have been stablished, it is rather obvious which path you should take since you only need to multiply both formulas. This is the link: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391404/generalization-of-the-half-angle-formulas

Answer (score -1):

You can prove Bretschneider’s formula, then by giving appropriate values to the variables in the formula, prove the other two
For Brahmagupta, the angle in the formula becomes 90, thus making the cosine zero, and the latter part of the formula disappears
For Heron, substitute d by zero